# Check cause of ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, neo4j

In neo4j 2.0 if you try to place a constraint on an index that already has a constraint it throws `ConstraintViolationException` which is caused by `AlreadyConstrainedException`

My question is: How do you check if `ConstraintViolationException` was caused by `ALreadyConstrainedException` or if it was something else? I've spent several hours googling and trying different things. The following code works, but feels hacky, so I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

```
catch(ConstraintViolationException e){
        if(e.getCause().getClass().getCanonicalName().equals("org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.AlreadyConstrainedException")){
            System.out.println("Index Already Constrained.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why don't you first check if it already has a constraint ? And then try to add it unless it already has one on the specific property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is close, but a bit hard to follow. The following slight improvement would be easier to understand. I assume your module will import AlreadyConstrainedException.

```
catch(ConstraintViolationException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof AlreadyConstrainedException){
       System.out.println("Index Already Constrained.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also check for the existence of the constraint upfront, using this call.

```
for (ConstraintDefintion def : db.schema().getConstraints( label )) {
     if (def.isConstraintType(ConstraintType.UNIQUENESS) && 
         asCollection(def.getPropertyKeys()).contains(key)) 
           return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: Do you know if there are any performance reasons to check it upfront rather than the way I'm doing it?

Comment: Using exceptions for control flow is usually not a good idea. It depends if you have this case quite often or really seldom. If you set up constraint information once upfront in your app you should be fine (as long as you don't change it dynamically)